# how to install Tkinter module in pycharm in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm

hey i'am new in programming ..

I am doing a mini project in python in pycharm..

I am getting an error which says Tkinter module not installed..

plzz anybody can help..!!

Comment: What is your python version? (Exact version: 3.5 or 3.6 or 3.7)

Comment: I am using pycharm 2.4 version

Answer (score 1):

in case of Python3.6, tkinter is a part of the standard library available from when you install your python. However if you want to know if tkinter is installed just import it in the python console

```
import tkinter
```

if you didn't see any errors you are good to go.